# mono16 image is wrongly formed when using compressed image_transport

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, ros-kinetic, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am dealing with a 16-bit mono image, publishing it using image_transport. I have no issues with the raw data topic, I can view it directly, bag it, replay it, and view again. If I run `rostopic echo /cam/image | grep step` I get 1280 as the result.

When I'm using `image_view _image_transport:=compressed`, I get an error message saying this:

```
Unable to convert 'mono16' image for display: : 'Image is wrongly formed: step < width * byte_depth * num_channels or 640 != 640 * 2 * 1
```

I'm using a vanilla `image_transport` publisher without changing any parameters. Am I missing something or is this a bug in the image_transport plugins?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301149/mono16-image-is-wrongly-formed-when-using-compressed-image_transport/) by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 435 on 2018-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Compressed image transport only supports 8 bit image formats, so the 16 bit image you're using cannot be compressed by it. Is the image you're trying to compress a depth image? The [compressed depth image transport package](http://wiki.ros.org/compressed_depth_image_transport) is designed specifically for this.

Hopefully this package will get this working for you.

EDIT : This may be OpenCV doing something a bit strange. It uses the OS codecs for image encoding/decoding so it's possible it behaves differently on different systems. You could make a simple node to receive the compressed image and debug the formatting and memory layout of the resulting cv::Mat object.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2018-08-22**:
Is that documented? I don't see it on the wiki. I am dealing with an actual 16-bit image in the wild, not depth. Compressed depth image transport seems like it might work, though I was able to solve my problem by switching to PNG

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2018-08-22**:

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-22**:
This was from a project a while ago. I've just had a look into the source code and the OpenCV documentation, and it looks as though it should support 16 bit images with PNG compression without any problems. It uses cv::imencode and cv::imdecode under the hood.